# Allow only certains user posts to display on a page in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have two special users on my site. Let's call them user1 and user2. User 1 manages "user page 1" and user2 manages "user page 2". I want their posts to appear when I click on these links and only see their posts in Wordpress.

1. Should I use categories for this and if so, how do I create a link to only show posts from a certain category?
2. Do I need a module for this?
3. If the answer is still not clear, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wp_qurey() function to show posts from specific authors.

Display posts by author, using author id:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'author=123' );
```

Display posts by author, using author 'user_nicename':

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'author_name=rami' );
```

More details here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_author_posts_url()` to create a link to a page listing a specific author's posts: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url

The format of the link (if you just want to go ahead and test it in your browser first) will be `http://www.yoursite.com/author/authorname`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Copy your index page loop and then change query from post_per_page query to this and you're done.

```
   $query = new WP_Query( 'author_name=rami' );
```